# Long running unimportant query slows down other queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a cronjob that executes a long running query every 5 Minutes. This query is not time critical, it currently takes about 30 seconds to complete.

The problem is that while the query is executing, all other queries run substantially slower.

The query is very simple (no joins, uses index etc.) but reads a lot of data (1.5 mil rows, about 150 bytes of data per row).

I can not easily cache the results, as all the data can change at any time.

Is there any way to throttle this specific query?

**Edit:**
The query really is just:

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table;
```

**Edit 2:**
Okay, sorry to say this, but every single one of you is missing the point here. I'm asking if i can **throttle the query** and all the answers i get do not address the question at all. You all tell me to change the cronjob (i know i can), run it from cli (i don't wanna), getting the data in chunks etc.

Again i'm asking specifically **can i somehow execute a MySQL SELECT query as "not important" so that it does not steal all resources from other queries?**

Sorry if this sounds like a major rant, i do appreciate that you took the time to help :)

Comment: Why would you be returning 1.5 million rows in a job that runs every 30 seconds?  Where are the rows going?

Comment: The job runs every 5 minutes, the query takes about 30 seconds to complete. I need the data to calculate stuff (too long to explain here, but i *do* need all the data).

Comment: Yes but to what is the data going? 1.5 million rows being moved is almost certainly the reason for the slowdown and is unlikely to improve unless you can circumvent that moving (IE if it is going back into mysql then could you use an INSERT...SELECT?).

Comment: The data is not being moved. It is used to calculate things (in php), and then it results in a handfull of inserts (less than 30 per run).

Comment: Can you move some or all the calculations into mysql and thereby reduce the rows being transferred?

Comment: @smoove . . . You should see if you can do more of the work in the database than in php.  Doing the work in php *is* moving the data, from the database to the application layer.

Comment: I guess it depends on how "*It is used to calculate things (in php)*" - you might be able to do those calculations in mysql.

Comment: Unlike INSERT and UPDATE you can't set LOW_PRIORITY on a SELECT for obvious reasons. You may however be able to solve this problem by reducing the load. Perhaps you could only select rows that have changed since you last looked?

Comment: Suppose there was such a thing as priority of a SELECT statement and you were able to lower it, what do you think could be the result of that? The data would be fetched slower, so as not to hinder other activity on the server, but some rows of that table could be changed in the meantime – same as just selecting data in portions, with small pauses in-between.

Comment: Put on hold because it's unclear what i'm asking? Getting downvoted for pointing out that people miss the point (that is clearly statet in the original question: "Is there any way to throttle this specific query?"? AND again in the edit?!) I don't get it.

Comment: @Andriy M: The query currently runs for about 30 seconds, i'm sure rows are changing while the query executes. While not optimal, i can deal with that.

Comment: @Moob: yeah, but i currently don't have that information (time changed) - Hence the question IF there is an easy way out of this.

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't add a timestamp? `ALTER TABLE table ADD lastUpdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and update your cron `SELECT field1,field2 FROM table WHERE lastUpdated >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MIN)` (or better yet use the *actual* time that the cron was last run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google yielded [this](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/self-throttling-mysql-queries) answer to what appears to be the same issue you're facing. The article describes a query that's reading an entire table, and is using a lot of I/O; the solution is to read 1000 rows at a time, and then sleep for the length of time it took to retrieve those rows.

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but it appears to be a credible solution.

The code below is copied from the link and slightly modified to answer your question:

```
SELECT
  field1, field2, 
    CASE
      WHEN (@row_counter := @row_counter + 1) IS NULL THEN NULL
      WHEN @row_counter % 1000 = 0 THEN
        CASE
          WHEN (@time_now := SYSDATE()) IS NULL THEN NULL
          WHEN (@time_diff := (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @chunk_start_time, @time_now))) IS NULL THEN NULL
          WHEN SLEEP(@time_diff) + test.prove_it(CONCAT('will sleep for ', @time_diff, ' seconds')) IS NULL THEN NULL
          WHEN (@chunk_start_time := SYSDATE()) IS NULL THEN NULL
          ELSE 0
        END
      ELSE 0
    END AS rental_id,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, rental_date, return_date) AS rental_days
FROM
  table,
  (SELECT @row_counter := 0) sel_row_counter,
  (SELECT @chunk_start_time := NOW()) sel_chunk_start_time
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a loop in PHP and retrieve the data in batches of say 100,000 rows, with a sleep of a few milliseconds between each batch. Not perfect but this would give other queries a bit more of a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching five megarows from the MySQL server to the client (cronjob process) issuing this query in thirty seconds is decent performance.  You aren't going to improve it more than marginally.

(I suppose you could invest in super-high-performance data center gear to improve it; in that case you might double it. That's not good enough to resolve a once-every-five-minute slowdown).

The reason your system is slowing down is that MySQL is trying to return consistent results to your `SELECT` operation. It queues or holds off inserts and updates to your table while it's pushing your results to your client.

How can you beat that problem? The best way is to fix the cronjob process. The ideal situation would be to run the computation in the database system instead of in the cronjob.  That is, something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(column) AS colsum, MAX(column2) AS colmax, DATE(timecolumn) AS day
  FROM table
 GROUP BY DATE(timecolumn)
```

You haven't told us what your cronjob is doing with those five million rows, so I am just showing this query as an example. This sort of thing will process the table, but return FAR fewer rows. It also can be optimized.

The second best solution would be to retrieve rows chunk by chunk instead of all together.

Another solution is to switch the tables to MyISAM. This gets rid of the transactional semantics. It might mess up the rest of your application.

You also could build a slave MySQL server to use for this sort of reporting query if need be.

Now maybe you're not allowed to change the cronjob or the infrastructure. If you can't make any of those algorithmic or infrastructural changes, you may have a candidate for http://thedailywtf.com/ .  There is no magic that makes mass data transfer hundreds of times faster.

Comment: A megarow is a thousand kilorows. A kilorow is a thousand rows.

Comment: So what's a yottarow?

Comment: A yottarow is a lotta rows. Specifically it's 10 raised to the power (8 * 3) rows. The Greek word for 8 is οκτώ  which somehow got twisted to "yoto"

Answer (score -1):

If you can call your query entirely from the command line (and assuming you're running on a Linux/UNIX/OS X system), you can lower the scheduling priority by using `nice`, e.g.:

`nice -n 19 mysql -u vivek -p -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes' cbzquotes`

The query will likely take longer to execute, but should not have such a negative effect on other processes.

Comment: sorry i can't, the query is part of a cronjob (written in php) and i need the data in the script.

Comment: Seems to me still possible via shell_exec, no?

Comment: And/or read from file. (I think shell_exec deals with output from the command as a single string, and 1.5 million records will blow that up real good.

Comment: Lowering the priority of the MySQL client will serve only to extend the time it takes to run the offending query. Lowering the client priority doesn't touch the `mysqld` priority.